# 404 on REST @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a 404 error here, but I just can't see it.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ep</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ep</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ep/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my ep-servlet.xml (Only "beans" tags surround the following code):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="server.service2">
</context:component-scan>
```

Here is the class itself:

```
package server.service2;
....

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginService
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/check/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void checkUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username)
    {
    }
}
```

The url i'm hitting with a browser is:

```
http://<server>:<correct-port>/ep/user/check/username
```

And it comes back with a 404! Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be hitting `http://<server>:<correct-port>/ep/ep/user/check/username`? i.e. two ep's

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Amorgos you can order your files to next:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ep</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ep</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Add Support for Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

ep-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="server.service2" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<!-- Register the bean -->
<beans:bean class="server.service2.LoginService" />
```

**I hopes these helps :)**